# Collection_check_boxes error after upgrading to Rails 7.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I recently upgraded a project from Rails 4 to Rails 7. I have a view page that uses checkboxes that is now throwing an error stating

> ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1):
> app/views/messages/new.html.erb:86
> app/views/messages/new.html.erb:84
> app/views/messages/new.html.erb:37

This view is a form that allows the user to submit a new message and check off multiple categories they want to associate with the message. The code for the view messages/new.html.erb is below:

```
    

    

    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom sticky-top center font-weight-bold">
            <h2>New Question
            </h2>
    
          <div class="container">
           <div class="page-header">
          <%= form_with model: @message, url: new_user_message_path, class: "form- 
    control" do 
         |f| %>
                <% if @message.errors.any? %>
                  <div id="error_explanation">
                    <h2>There were some errors:</h2>
                    <ul>
                      <% @message.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                        <li><%= message %></li>
                      <% end %>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
          </nav>
    
    
        <div class="container">
          <div class="container-fluid mx-auto text-nowrap text-dark" style="width: 
     500px;">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                  <div class="col sign-in card-title card-body">
    
                    <div class="field<%= ' field_with_errors' if 
     @message.errors[:title].any? 
        %>">
                      <%= f.label :title %><br>
                      <%= f.text_field :title, value: @message.title, class: "span5" %> 
    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="field<%= ' field_with_errors' if 
        @message.errors[:question].any? %>">
                      <%= f.label :question %><br>
                      <%= f.text_field :question, value: @message.question, class: 
     "span5" %> 
       </div>
                     <br>
                     <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                     <br>
                      <%= f.hidden_field :patient_id, value: current_user.id, class: 
    "form- 
       control" %>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <%= f.label :new_or_preexisting_condition%><br>
                      <%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all[0..1], 
    :id, 
        :category do |b| %>
                      <div> 
                      <%=b.label %>
                      </div>
                      <% end %>
                    </div>
                    <br> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <%= f.label :affected_system%><br>
                      <%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all[2..11], 
     :id, 
        :category do |b| %>
                      <div>
                      <%=b.check_box %>
                      <%= b.label %>
                      </div>
                      <% end %>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="actions">
                      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                    </div>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>  
        </div>
        </div>
```

The models are as follows:

Message.rb

```
    

    class Message < ApplicationRecord
          belongs_to :patient, foreign_key: :patient_id
          has_many :message_categories
          has_many :categories, through: :message_categories
          has_many :responses
          has_many :physicians, through: :responses
          validates :title, presence: true
          validates :question, presence: true
          accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
          accepts_nested_attributes_for :message_categories
          scope :new_condition, -> {joins(:categories).merge(Category.new_condition)}
          scope :existing_condition, -> 
          {joins(:categories).merge(Category.existing_condition)}
          scope :unanswered_questions, -> {left_outer_joins(:responses).where(responses: 
         {message_id: nil})}
    
          def responses_attributes=(responses_attributes)
              responses_attributes.values.each do |response_attribute|
              response = Response.find_or_create_by(response_attribute)
              self.response_attributes.build(response: response)
            end
          end
        end
```

Category.rb

```
    class Category < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :message_categories
      has_many :messages, through: :message_categories
      scope :new_condition, -> { where("category_id == 1") }
      scope :existing_condition, -> { where("category_id == 2") }
    
    end
```

MessageCategory.rb

```
    class MessageCategory < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :message
      belongs_to :category
    end
```

Patient.rb

```
    class Patient < User
      has_secure_password
      belongs_to :user, optional: true
      has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
      validates :name, :email, :password_digest, presence: true
      validates :email, uniqueness: true
      validates :name, length: { minimum: 2 }
    
    #validations specific to this model
    
      def self.model_namev#build correct path
        User.model_name
      end
    end
```

User.rb

```
    Class User < ApplicationRecord
       has_secure_password
       scope :patients, -> { where(type: 'Patient') } 
       scope :physicians, -> { where(type: 'Physician') }
       has_many :physicians
       has_many :patients
    
    
    end
```

The Messages controller:

```
    # frozen_string_literal: true
    
    # class containing messages CRUD methods
    class MessagesController < ApplicationController
      before_action :logged_in? 
      before_action :patient_user, only: [:new, :edit, :update]
    
      def new
           if params[:user_id] && Patient.exists?(params[:user_id])
           @message = Message.new(patient_id: params[:user_id])
           @categories = Category.all 
          else
          flash[:notice] = 'You do not have access to this feature.'
          redirect_to controller: 'users', action: 'show', id: current_user.id
          end
      end
    
      def show
         @message = Message.find(params[:id])
      end
    
      def index
        @messages = if params[:user_id]
                  Message.where(patient_id: params[:user_id])
                else
                  Message.all
                end
      end
    
      def create
        @message = Message.new(message_params)
        if @message.save
          flash[:notice] = 'Message successfully created'
          redirect_to controller: 'users', action: 'show', id: current_user.id
        else
          render :new
        end
      end
    
      def edit
          if params[:user_id]
            patient = Patient.find_by(id: params[:patient_id])
            if patient = nil
              redirect_to controller: 'users', action: 'show', id: current_user.id
            else
              @message = Message.find_by(id: params[:id])
            end
          else
            flash[:notice] = 'You do not have access to this feature.'
            redirect_to controller: 'users', action: 'show', id: current_user.id
          end
      end
    
      def update
          @message = Message.find(params[:id])
          @message.update(message_params)
          flash[:notice] = 'Message successfully updated'
          render :show
      end
    
      def destroy
        @message = Message.find(params[:id])
        @message.delete
        flash[:notice] = 'Message successfully deleted'
        redirect_to controller: 'users', action: 'show'
      end
    
      private
    
      def message_params
        params.require(:message).permit(:title, :question, :patient_id, category_ids: [])
      end
    end
```

The Categories controller

```
    # frozen_string_literal: true
    
    # class containing categories CRUD methods
    class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    
      def show
        @category = Category.find(params[:id])
      end
    
      def create
        @category = Category.create(category_params)
        if @category.save
          redirect_to 'messages/show'
        else
          flash[:notice] = 'Unable to save categories. Please try again.'
          redirect_to 'messages/new'
        end
      end
    
      def index
        @categories = Category.all 
      end
    
      private
    
      def category_params
        params.require(:category).permit(:category, :id)
      end
    end
```

I'm not sure if it has something to do with the fact that categories is related to messages through message categories?

Comment: Your phrase "upgraded a project from Rails 4 to Rails 7" is a red marker for me. According the upgrading guide (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#the-upgrade-process), you should upgrade to each minor version, i.e. 4 -> 5.0 -> 5.1 -> 6.0 -> 6.1 -> 7.0, and after each step check if something is broken. There could be so many reasons, why it stopped working, and what else is not working.

Comment: Thank you. I did just that and I got it to work.